# Select XElements from comma separated values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using LINQ-to-XML in my project and I want to extract only those elements which are in comma separated string i.e.

Here is sample from XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Entity>Employee</Entity>
    <EntityID>2857</EntityID>
    .. some more nodes...
    .. some more nodes...
  </Table>
    <Table>
    <Entity>Employee</Entity>
    <EntityID>2856</EntityID>
    .. some more nodes...
    .. some more nodes...
  </Table>
 .......
</NewDataSet>
```

Here is my `XElement`:

```
 XElement MainEntities = XElement.Load(strFileName);
 IEnumerable<XElement> EntityElements;
 EntityElements = MainEntities.Elements("Table").Where(xtab => (string)xtab.Element("Entity").Value == "Employee");
```

and the comma separated string is

```
var filter = new List<string> { strEmployeeIds };
```

I tried

```
EntityElements = MainEntities.Elements("Table").Where(xtab => (string)xtab.Element("Entity").Value == "Employee" && filter.Contains((string)xtab.Element("EntityID").Value));
```

but it's not working...

How can I got only those elements which are in `filter`  from `EntityElements`;

Comment: Your LINQ statements seems fine. can you post an XML sample as well?

Comment: Do you mean `strEmployeeIds` contains comma separated string like : `"1,2,3,4"` ?

Comment: @ReinderWit, I did updated the question with sample xml

Comment: @har07 Yes, you are right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `strEmployeeIds` is defined something like this:

```
string strEmployeeIds = "1,2,3";
```

You would need to split the string to make a list out of it:

```
string[] filter = strEmployeeIds.Split(',');
```

Comment: Or `string[] filter = strEmployeeIds.Split(',');`. The usage in the Linq expression doesn't really require wrapping the array in a list.

Comment: Yes, it's working.. I was doing a mistake that I am adding it as comma separated string..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this :

```
var filter = "1,2,3,4";
EntityElements = 
        MainEntities.Elements("Table")
                    .Where(xtab => 
                            (string)xtab.Element("Entity").Value == "Employee" && 
                             filter.Split(new[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                   .Contains((string)xtab.Element("EntityID").Value)
                           );
```